# Valid signing identity not found with xcode 4.2 but working in xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2, xcode4.5, provisioning-profile

I have an working set of valid provisioning profile and certificate. this will working in the latest xcode 4.5 in this version we can set the deployment target only to 4.3 but we need to deploy in 4.0 also for that i have trying to run the same code with same certificate and provisioning profile in xcode 4.2 in ios 10.6.1 System but i get **"valid singing identity not found error."**

Any one please help i need to know the reason for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please give us a bit more information...

Comment: Hi i have created one new project in latest xcode 4.5 and have created development certificates and provision profile for that and i run the application in my iPhone 4 with deployment target 4.3. now we need the application to run on ios 4.0 also but its not posible in xcode 4.5 so i have moved my coding and to another system with xcode 4.2 in that i set the deployment target as 4.0 and but the same set of certificate and provision profile not working in the xcode version 4.2. i need to check that with my ipod(ios 4.1) that is also in my provision profile.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have installed the Development | Distribution certificates on the system that with xcode 4.0. You can export the certificates and keys from the KeyChain of one computer where projects runs and then install these certificates and keys to other system. If still they show the error you should try to quit the xcode and key chain and in some cases might have to restart system.

Comment: I have tried this step. but the no change. the same error came.